# Experience using the SugarCRM Outlook Plugin Across two hosted solutions?

Tags: outlook-2007, sugarcrm

We are looking to migrate a client from a locally supported version of MS Office (including Outlook) to a hosted version. this won't be the "web-based verison" of Outlook-- but moving to a hosted provider that provides remote access to the Window/Office environment.

We are looking to maintain the connection with the SugarCRM Outlook plugin. The client is currently using Sugar Professional hosted by SugarCRM.

What changes to the SugarCRM Outlook plugin need to be made to bridge between two hosted versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the Impossible Mission team, Sugar will disavow any outlook plug-in operation beyond a stand alone desktop. However, if the computer in question allows each individual to have their own profile in a remote desktop session (with something like Windows 2008 R2). I don't see how you would have any problems. Just don't tell Sugar I said anything, they think their the only ones in here!

Answer (score 1):

If it's just an ordinary hosted Outlook (accessed with e.g. Remote Desktop), you properly only need to install (with admin rights) the Sugar outlook plugin on the hosted environment/outlook and configure it like before.

The Sugar outlook plugin is a client-side plugin, so if you are able to install it on the hosted environment, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Outlook Plugin will work with the web-based version of Outlook.

Comment: Thank you. I clarrified the question. This would not be the "web-based" version of Outlook, but the full version provided as a hosted/managed solution.

Comment: Would this be in something like a Citrix environment?